# By implementing an interface, does a class become a "Type" of that inteface?

Tags: java, oop

I thought when a class implements an interface, it is saying that it "Can do" whats defined in the interface.I am also under impression that "Is a" or "Type of" notation is for class hierarchy, meaning a class inheriting from superclass. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Based on the article here : http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2009/02/12/learn-this-when-to-use-an-abstract-class-and-an-interface/ . It says when a class extends an abstract class it establishes "Is A" relationship but with interface it is establishing "Can-do" relationship. Whats the use of interface if both abstract class and interface are establishing "IS A" relationship? Lets not get into multiple inheritance and other basic stuff....

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. People should comment at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the title Question I would say no.

There have been answers saying yes and showed this by using instanceof, however when reading the Java language specification it states.

> two reference types are the same run-time type if:
>   They are both class or both interface types, are defined by the same class loader, and have the same binary name

And a class implementing an interface won't receive the binary name of the interface.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Yes. This is evident from use of the `instanceof` operator:</del>

```
    interface I { }

    class A implements I { }

    ...

    static boolean isAnI(Object obj) {
       return (obj instanceof I);
    }
```

<del>Here, calling `isAnI(new A())` will return `true`.</del>

**EDIT:** after understanding the question better, I think this comes down to the formal definition of *IS-A* in Java. Wikipedia article on the general OO definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). From this inheritance-hierarchy based perspective, I would change my answer to no, agreeing with Farmor's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.  But, the interface does say what the class "Can do" but then you can also cast an object of that interface and run the methods of the interface.  Polymorphism at work.